# video.js is not working in IE 8, 9, 10 h.aa is not an object

Tags: internet-explorer, object, video.js

I have a problem with IE.

In my head section:

```
<link href="js/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/video-js/video.js"></script>
<script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "js/video-js/video-js.swf"</script>
```

And in my body section:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls preload="none" width="480" height="360" poster="media/movies/jpg/000/28.jpg">
<source src="http://www.example.com/media/movies/flv/000/28.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

And in my javascript file:

```
videojs("example_video_1", { "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "none" });
```

I'm getting error in console: h.aa is empty or is not an object in video.js row:47 col:128

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have Flash player installed? If you use the images from modern.ie then you have to install flash yourself if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thank you @roelkok. Installing the flash player also fixes "this.h is null or not an object"